# На странице инструментов модератора (при нехватке репутации) вместо "привилегий" упоминаются "права"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, привилегии

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить на "странице привилегий".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/4733

Новый перевод:

> Посетите страницу привилегий, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию о правах, которые можно заработать.